# Should each syntax of SASS be given its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

**SCSS VS. INDENTED SYNTAX**

**Is SCSS different from indented syntax enough that they should have separate tags?**

From the SASS documentation:

> Syntax
>
> There are two syntaxes available for Sass. The first, known as SCSS (Sassy CSS) and used throughout this reference, is an extension of the syntax of CSS3. This means that every valid CSS3 stylesheet is a valid SCSS file with the same meaning. In addition, SCSS understands most CSS hacks and vendor-specific syntax, such as IE’s old filter syntax. This syntax is enhanced with the Sass features described below. Files using this syntax have the .scss extension.
>
> The second and older syntax, known as the indented syntax (or sometimes just “Sass”), provides a more concise way of writing CSS. It uses indentation rather than brackets to indicate nesting of selectors, and newlines rather than semicolons to separate properties. Some people find this to be easier to read and quicker to write than SCSS. The indented syntax has all the same features, although some of them have slightly different syntax; this is described in the indented syntax reference. Files using this syntax have the .sass extension.

Information Taken from [SASS Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)

---

There is a good debate going on, [on this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/39890/18427):

> Sass is the name of the CSS preprocessor, which has 2 syntaxes: scss and sass. There's no reason to have an scss tag. – cimmanon 15 mins ago
>
> it is a separate syntax [stackoverflow.com/a/5654471/1214743](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654447/1214743) – Malachi 15 mins ago
>   @cimmanon I'm using the SCSS syntax. Isn't that a reason? – kleinfreund 15 mins ago
>
> No. Look at the tag description for [sass]. It has nothing to do with the sass syntax. If you look over on SO, there is no scss tag, only an alias to sass (see: stackoverflow.com/tags/sass/info). – cimmanon 7 mins ago
>
> is CSS different from CSS3? SCSS can be converted to SASS or indented syntax. they are totally different, and this isn't SO – Malachi 4 mins ago   edit
>
> @Malachi CSS3 is an addition to CSS. – kleinfreund 3 mins ago
>
> and SASS 3 is an addition to SASS(2?) which uses the new Syntax. there is a difference – Malachi 2 mins ago  edit
>
> @Malachi I think you don't got cimmanon's point. The two syntaxes are both part of SASS. So there is no need for a SCSS tag, but rather a synonym to SASS. – kleinfreund 1 min ago
>
> ok. .net encompasses asp.net and mvc.net are they the same? SASS encompasses indented Syntax and SCSS Syntax. they are separate and do different things – Malachi 7 secs ago  edit

Comment: The SASS docs mention that the _intended syntax_ sometimes is simply known as SASS, somewhat making it just the standard syntax and SCSS being the alternative syntax. Therefor the existing tags should be enough (i.e. `SASS` and `SCSS`). But I'm not entirely sure on how to handle it here.

Comment: @kleinfreund one uses indentation and the other uses brackets.  your argument would be like saying that VB and C# are the same because they are both .NET and the only difference is the way a block of code is specified, brackets or indentation.

Comment: I'm not saying SASS and SCSS are the same thing, but they are pretty similar. I simply don't know if there is any benefit in having tags for the two syntaxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no benefit to splintering the Sass tag for the purpose of differentiating between sass and scss syntax.

- Tags are *supposed* to useful for future users, not just the asker:  users are by far more likely to search for "sass" than "scss"
- All examples on the Sass website use the scss syntax (the old site design used to show both syntaxes side by side)
- While scss syntax is the preferred syntax among users, the name of the preprocessor is still Sass and so is command to compile Sass files
- Sass and scss can be used within the same project as long as you don't try and mix syntaxes within the same file
- Google for `sass css` and `scss css`: the later will give about half as many results

> and SASS 3 is an addition to SASS(2?) which uses the new Syntax. there is a difference

I don't understand the point being made here.  Every version of Sass includes new features just like every other piece of software on the planet.  There's just not enough Sass related questions to warrant breaking down the tag by version or syntax.

The appropriate thing to do is make [scss] a synonym of [sass] rather than make it a full fledged tag.  As already stated, [scss] is a synonym of [sass] on Stack Overflow.  Before I proposed the synonym over there, questions with the [scss] tag were few and far between and nearly all questions with the [sass] tag were using the scss syntax anyway.